# How to count time interval on raspberry pi 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, raspberry-pi, sensors

How can I count the time interval on Raspberry Pi 4 ? I have connected a magnetic switch sensor to the Pi and a Piezo buzzer. The Piezo buzzer must turned ON if the magnetic switch sensor input value equal 1 for more than 2 minutes. otherwise the piezo buzzer must be turned off.

I have used the function `millis()` on Arduino to measure the time interval like this :

```
long previoustime = 0;
long  interval = 30000; //5 minutes
long currenttime = millis();

if (i == 5){ // Password correct open the door 
  setLocked(false);
 previoustime = currenttime;
}

if (currenttime - previoustime >= interval) {
if(ServoMotor.read()==90){
setLocked(true);
 i=1;
 }
}
```

But it's different for the Raspberry Pi I have tried several functions but nothing works.
 Here is my code (without the time interval counter ) :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


PizeoPin = 31
MagneticSwitchPin = 12

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#Set Magnetic contact switch sensor as an input
GPIO.setup(MagneticSwitchPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(PizeoPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(PizeoPin,GPIO.LOW)


while True:

    if GPIO.input(12):
        print("opened")
        GPIO.output(PizeoPin,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
           

       
    if GPIO.input(12) == False:
       print("closed")
       GPIO.output(PizeoPin,GPIO.LOW)
```

Can anyone help me to correct it please ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you wanted. It won't be exactly 2 minutes but should be close enough for your purposes.

```
from collections import deque

interval = 60 * 2 # 2 minutes to seconds
vals = deque([False]*interval, maxlen=interval)
buzzing = False

while True:
    
    vals.append(GPIO.input(MagneticSwitchPin))
    
    if not buzzing:
        if all(vals):
            print("opened")
            GPIO.output(PizeoPin,GPIO.HIGH)   
            buzzing = True          

    if buzzing:
        if not all(vals):
            print("closed")
            GPIO.output(PizeoPin,GPIO.LOW)
            buzzing = False

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working, it prints number 16 on the shell (MagneticSwitchPin's number). Is there any other way to do it ?